# How do I get rid of the gaps between these rows?

Tags: html, css, image

I am working on an exercise where I create a grid of photos 4x3. I have removed the gap between photos within rows by removing the spacing in the HTML but the gaps between rows I can not seem to remove. Any help?

https://codepen.io/benrichi/pen/MJgOze?editors=1100

HTML

```
<section id="section_photography">
    <h1>Photography</h1>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" class="photography_image"><img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" class="photography_image"><img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" class="photography_image"><img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" class="photography_image"><img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" class="photography_image"><img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" class="photography_image"><img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" class="photography_image"><img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" class="photography_image"><img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" class="photography_image"><img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" class="photography_image"><img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" class="photography_image"><img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" class="photography_image">
</section>
```

CSS

```
#section_photography {
    width: 100vw;
    padding-top: 50px;
    background-color: aqua;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
}

#section_photography h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

.photography_image {
    width: 25vw;
    margin: none;
    padding: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use vertical align:

```
.photography_image {
    width: 25vw;
    margin: none;
    padding: none;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

**Explanation:**
Images are placed on the baseline by inline property (default), so the space below them is the space reserved for font descenders (g,j,p,q and y). `vertical-align: bottom` get them to sit at the bottom of the line box.

Comment: That worked perfectly, is there an explanation as to why this works?